# Create Calculated Pivot from Several Query Results in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have question regarding how to make a calculated pivot table from several query results on PostgreSQL. I've managed to make three queries results but don't have any idea how to combine and calculate all the data into a single table. I've tried to google it but found out that most of the question is about how to make a pivot table from a single table, which I'm able to do using `sum`, `case`, and `group by`. Well, Here's the simplified version of my query results

Query from query 1 which contains gross value

`| city  | code | gross  |
|-------|------|--------|
| city1 | 21   | 194793 |
| city1 | 25   | 139241 |
| city1 | 28   | 231365 |
| city2 | 21   | 282025 |
| city2 | 25   | 334458 |
| city2 | 28   | 410852 |
| city3 | 21   | 109237 |`

Result from query 2 which contains positive adjustments

`| city  | code | adj_pos |
|-------|------|---------|
| city1 | 21   | 16259   |
| city1 | 25   | 13634   |
| city1 | 28   | 45854   |
| city2 | 25   | 18060   |
| city2 | 28   | 18220   |`

Result from query 3 which contains negative adjustments

`| city  | code | adj_neg |
|-------|------|---------|
| city1 | 25   | 23364   |
| city2 | 21   | 27478   |
| city2 | 25   | 23474   |`

And what I **want** to to is to create something like this

`| city  | 21_gross | 25_gross | 28_gross | 21_pos | 25_pos | 28_pos | 21_neg | 25_neg | 28_neg |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| city1 | 194793   | 139241   | 231365   | 16259  | 13634  | 45854  |        | 23364  |        |
| city2 | 282025   | 334458   | 410852   |        | 18060  | 18220  | 27478  | 23474  |        |
| city3 | 109237   |          |          |        |        |        |        |        |        |`

or probably final calculation which come from gross + positive adjustment -
negative adjustment from each city on each code like this

`| city  | 21_nett | 25_nett | 28_nett |
|-------|---------|---------|---------|
| city1 | 211052  | 129511  | 277219  |
| city2 | 254547  | 329044  | 429072  |
| city3 | 109237  | 0       | 0       |`

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can achieve is to get the pivoting part as JSON - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b7d64/23:

```
select 
  city,
  json_object_agg(
    code,
    coalesce(gross,0) + coalesce(adj_pos,0) - coalesce(adj_neg,0)
  ) as js
from q1
  left join q2 using (city,code)
  left join q3 using (city,code)
group by city
```